# I want to store the onchange value of option and store to a php variable

Tags: php, html-select, onchange

I want to store the onchange value of option and store to a php variable

```html
<select class="form-control" name="users"  >
     <option value="#">Please Select Your Employee</option>
     <?php  while($rows = mysql_fetch_row($res)){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $rows[0]; ?>">
     <?php  echo "\r\n $rows[0]";}?>
     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You cannot store a javascript variable (clientside) in a PHP variable (serverside). And the above code will produce a row of onclosed `<option>`-tags. Where is the `onchange`-event?

Comment: please tell i want to store the select value to php variable help me

Comment: Loose from the solution, you should start to use the PHP extension mysqli instead of mysql. The mysql extention is deprecated and removed from PHP from version 5.5.0. See http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function myfunction(){
    a = document.getElementById('myselect').value;
    location.href="?a="+a;
   }
  </script>
 </head>

<body>
  <select id="myselect" onchange="myfunction()">     
     <option value="10" <?php if($_GET['a']== 10 ) echo "selected"; ?> > value 10 </option>
     <option value="20" <?php if($_GET['a']== 20 ) echo "selected"; ?> > value 20 </option>
     <option value="30" <?php if($_GET['a']== 30 ) echo "selected"; ?> > value 30 </option>
  </select>

 <?php   
    if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
      $val = $_GET['a'];
      echo $val;
    }
    else{
      $val = 0;
      echo $val;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```